# Pointer-to-pointer arithmetic not behaving as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

I have the code below and can't understand why it is segfaulting. Where am I messing up here. I am trying to learn how to access/modify a char **. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char * wordPtr;
    char **wordPtrPtr = &wordPtr;
    *wordPtrPtr = (char *) malloc(3 * sizeof(char));

    *wordPtrPtr[0] = 'A';
    *wordPtrPtr[1] = 'B';
    *wordPtrPtr[2] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", *wordPtrPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*wordPtrPtr[index]` --> `(*wordPtrPtr)[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You need to dereference `wordPtrPtr` first before accessing array elements:

```
(*wordPtrPtr)[0] = 'A';
(*wordPtrPtr)[1] = 'B';
(*wordPtrPtr)[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: Or `wordPtrPtr[0][0] = …`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this

```
 wordPtr[0] = 'A';
 wordPtr[1] = 'B';
 wordPtr[2] = '\0';
```

Or

```
*(*wordPtrPtr +0) = 'A';
*(*wordPtrPtr +1) = 'B';
*(*wordPtrPtr +2) = '\0';
```